# Using kubernetes secret env var inside another env var

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, environment-variables

I have a secret being used as env var in another env var as follows:

```
- name: "PWD"
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: "credentials"
      key: "password"
- name: HOST
  value: "xyz.mongodb.net"
- name: MONGODB_URI 
  value: "mongodb+srv://user:$(PWD)@$(HOST)/db_name?"
```

When i exec into the container and run `env` command to see the values of env i see -

```
mongodb+srv://user:password123  
@xyz.mongodb.net/db_name?
```

The container logs show error as authentication failure.
Is this something that is expected to work in kubernetes ? There [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/) talk about dependent env vars but do not give example using secrets. Did not find clear explanation on this after extensive search. Only found [this](https://joeblogs.technology/2020/12/concatenating-kubernetes-secrets-for-environment-variables/) one article doing something similar.

Some points to note -

- The secret is a sealed secret.
- This is the final manifest's contents, but all this is templated using helm.
- The value is being used inside a spring boot application

Is the new line after `123` expected ?
If this evaluation of env from a secret in another env is possible then what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the command used to encode the secret - `echo "pasword" | base64`. The echo adds a newline character at the end of the string. Using `echo -n "password" | base64` fixed the secret.
Closing the issue.